# The operation can’t be completed because the original item for “Новый том” can’t be found

Tags: macos, network, wifi, smb, hdd

I have external hdd that I've connected to my wifi router Keenetic extra. I've enabled CIFS and FTP in router USB settings page.
I can see this HDD folders in terminal using ls without a problem, but I have error trying to connect to it via finder.

I've already tried solutions from this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131613/the-operation-can-t-be-completed-because-the-original-item-for-foo-can-t-be-fo), none of them works for me.
It seems very strange to me that two unix systems (os x and the linux on router) should use some windows-origin protocol SMB to share files with each other in the first place, actually, but alright.

I've also read that os x use some proprietary smb implementation, and that could be the source of the problem, but I don't want to bother to install samba manually right now. How to diagnose this error or maybe there is some workarounds?

Comment: I'd try changing its name to something non-unicode, at least as a test. Just try New Volume, or even NewVolume.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue from my Ubuntu file server and iMac running El Capitan. The way I solved it is to make sure the samba guest account in Linux has read access to the directory I'm sharing. I did this by adding `guest account = foo` under the `[global]` section of /etc/samba/smb.conf and making sure that user `foo` has read access to the directories I'm sharing. For reference, my share definitions (at the bottom of smb.conf) look like this:

```
[share_name]
  path = /media/path_to_directory
  browseable = yes
  read only = yes
  guest ok = yes
```