# The operation can’t be completed because the original item for “Foo” can’t be found - Mounting .dmg

Tags: finder, dmg

I've seen this error message referenced a lot in relation to connecting to network shares (see [The operation can’t be completed because the original item for “Foo” can’t be found](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131613/the-operation-can-t-be-completed-because-the-original-item-for-foo-can-t-be-fo)) but I am having this when trying to mount some DMGs.

I have tried the DMGs I am trying to mount on a different Mac and it works fine. I have also tried the permission/group changes and relaunching Finder from the previous question, but still no luck.

Comment: I've solved the immediate problem, by extracting the contents of the .dmg on my other Mac and copying over the network, but I'd still like to be able to mount all .dmgs on both of my Macs.

Comment: I'm now getting this when trying to use a USB memory stick, which has previously worked on this  Mac.