# Cannot connect to SAMBA shares drive after update to Catalina

Tags: network, catalina, smb

I have a raspberry pi 4b running raspbian buster lite, connected to this I have a 1TB HDD, on Mojave I was able to connect to the network folder and access the files on it, however with the new Catalina update I get this when I try to access it (I can still see it) "The operation can’t be completed because the original item for “RASPBERRY FOLDER” can’t be found."
Is there any way to fix this or connect to the folder/files a different way?

Comment: Hi and welcome! could you clarify a bit on *when I try to access it* ? How do you do so? Command line, GUI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn off packet signing for SMB 2 and SMB 3 connections as described in
https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT205926:

- Edit `/etc/nsmb.conf` (create it if necessary)
- Add

  ```
  [default]
  signing_required=no
  ```
- Save file
- Reconnect SMB shares (or reboot your Mac)

Comment: For me it was: Hold the Option key and right-click the Finder icon in the Dock, then select Relaunch.

Answer (score 0):

This insight gave me the ANSWER to fix my concerns...
trying the different connection prefixes one gave me the answer - cifs:\

IT works for the MOMENT

not sure why it versus Western Digital default answer of smb:\ or afp:\ or other concoctions of prefixes would change permissions to files...IT WORKS (more inquisitive research may be involved - why fix a broken command) !

Comment: This makes no sense - 1). using the URL `cifs://` is for mounting a *remote* file system.  2) `cifs://` and `smb://` are the exact same thing - in other words, using `cifs://` doesn't call a different command.  See `man mount_smbfs` for details on both points.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and solved it in a strange way, 
As we are all aware Mac user has actually 2 names: one is the username (the profile name if i may) and the Display name.

Prior to Catalina , when authenticating with an SMB share from a Windows computer , I was using the display name (although it is a full name with a space) and everything was cool.

In Catalina , I found out I can only use the username, windows cannot authenticate with the display name.

of course , before I got to this point I have checked/enabled SMBv2, created the NetBios file in the MAC and all the other hints I could find, which obviously did not do the trick for me.

hope this helps

Comment: So what did actually work (what did you have to change to make it work again)?