# Unable to access a storage drive on one Mac from the other while both MacBook Pros are on the same network

Tags: network, hard-drive

So I have two Macbook Pros connected to the same network, lets call the first one John the second one Molly.
I connected a hard drive (lets call it Jr. ) to John and attempted to access Jr. while working on Molly over the network.

I get the following error message: "The operation can’t be completed because the original item for “Jr.” can’t be found."

I have replaced Jr. with other storage drives, and applied all of the solutions shown [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131613/the-operation-can-t-be-completed-because-the-original-item-for-foo-can-t-be-fo) with no success.

How can I get this to work?

Thanks

Comment: That error message assumes you connected it at least once.  Are you using DHCP for your MacBooks?  It's possible the IP address has changed.  How did you connect in the first place?

Comment: Hello @Allan, I am using DHCP. The IP address did change, and I changed it accordingly. I'm connected via Wi-fi and Thunderbolt Bridge. I've used both, and I still get the same error message.